# Dynamic Parameter Passing to BigQuery.IO connector in Apache Beam Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Hi am very new to Apache Beam and trying to create a Batch pipeline that loads incremental data from Big Query to the Spanner.

For this, I have to refer to spanner to get the timestamp of the last record inserted and pull data from a big query from that timestamp.

I Am trying to find a way to pass parameters to the query which I use in the big query connector as shown below code.

```
PCollection<Struct> metaInfo = getLastReadTimestamp(pipeline, options, uuid);
PCollection<TableRow> bqDataSet = getBQRecords(pipeline,options,metaInfo,uuid);
public PCollection<Struct> getLastReadTimestamp(Pipeline pipeline,
                                                CustomerMessageReaderOptions options,
                                                UUID uuid){

    PCollection<Struct> lastReadTimestamp = pipeline.apply("read from spanner",
            SpannerIO.read().withBatching(false)
                            .withInstanceId(options.getProject())
                            .withDatabaseId(options.getDataBaseName())
                            .withQuery("select max(create_datetime) as readtimestamp from customer_txn"));
    return lastReadTimestamp;
}

public PCollection<TableRow> getBQRecords(Pipeline pipeline,
                                          CustomerMessageReaderOptions options,
                                          PCollection<Struct> metadata,
                                          UUID uuid){
    String lastReadTime = "" ; //read from metadata
    String bqQuery = String.format("select * from `projectid.customerdataset.customer_txns where createtimestamp > '%s'`",lastReadTime);
    PCollection<TableRow> bqDataSet = pipeline.apply("read from BQ",
            BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.TypedRead.Method.DIRECT_READ)
                        .usingStandardSql()
                        .fromQuery(bqQuery));
    return bqDataSet;
}
```

So as seen in the above code in metaInfo(Pcolletion) I have the timestamp that I need to pass to the query to read data from Big Query in getBQRecords method.

I know that I can't declare variable values from pcollection as shown in the above code, this is not possible directly but I find a way to solve this problem

My question is there any way that I can achieve this, basically, a way to pass values to the query parameters dynamically with in the dataflow job itself?

Any suggestion can be helpful....!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The problem here, you have a Side input : the last timestamp from `Spanner` and your input from `Bigquery` depends on this side input. As I know but maybe I am wrong, the value of a side input can be retrieved in a DoFn, not in another IO.

Comment: How do you launch your `Dataflow` job ? Have you a `DAG` pipeline orchestrator like `Airflow` that launch your Dataflow job ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun thanks for the response, I have tried accessing this value inside a DoFn and tried setting up this query as one of the pipeline options, but unfortunately i can't access pipeline options inside doFn which is not allowed.

I have deployed this in a Kubernetes job that triggers the pod and creates the dataflow job in GCP.

Comment: You're welcome. You can get options in a `DoFn` but your problem here is to access to the side input value before calling you input source from `Bigquery`

Comment: I wanted to propose a solution in another direction but I need to know, how you launch your Dataflow job. Do you launch it with `maven` command or with `java -jar` with a fat jar, on your `Kubernetes` pod ?

Comment: Yes in Kubernetes pod I use maven and pass all the required arguments which will create the job in GCP

Answer (score 2):

I propose you a solution and I hope it can help.

In your `Kubernetes` `pod`, before to launch your `Dataflow` job in command line with `Maven`, you can follow these steps :

- Create a `shell` script
- Use `gcloud` command to execute your query to `Spanner` to get the last datetime in your `shell` script :

```bash
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql your-database --instance=your-instance --sql='select max(create_datetime) as readtimestamp from customer_txn'
```

- Get the result datetime from `Spanner`
- Pass the result datetime as a program argument in a `mvn` command line :

```
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=package.MainClass \
  -Dexec.args=" \
  --project=project \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --last_datetime=result_datetime_from_spanner
...
```

- Then in your `Beam` `Dataflow` get the last datetime as pipeline Option
- Pass this datetime to the `SQL` query to execute to `Bigquery` in the `BigqueryIO` proposed by `Beam`.

This solution delegates the responsibility of `Spanner` datetime retrieval outside of `Dataflow`. It adds a little complexity in the launching part but makes the `Dataflow` job easier.

In addition to having the permissions to launch the `Dataflow` job, the executor from the `Kubernetes` pod must have the permissions to read data from `Spanner`.

Comment: Thanks sound achievable and ill keep that in the list of options but am actually trying to get this done within the dataflow job.


Am also looking to other options for maintaining this as metadata info in Big Query itself so i don't need to pass the value but can handle it through a nested query in the main query this is one of the last options i have if i can't do this in the dataflow job itself.

Comment: Indeed, if you have this date in `Bigquery`, it will be very simpler and the data can be directly recovered in a single `sql` query from `Bigquery`.

Comment: Yeah but for this, i need to maintain a separate table like metadata info in BQ and store this timestamp after insert in the spanner.